# How to store data after confirm screen page

Tags: laravel-5

This is contact form. I would like to recive email and save this data to my mysql. I use Laravel. Email function works good. but There is a problem. I would like to store all data at "function complete".
I validate all data at "function confirm" This is confirm screen page so user still not submit yet. I tried to write code like this at "function complete" but error say "Undefined variable: request" Could you teach me how to fix my code please?

```
public function confirm(Request $request)
    {
      $rules = [   
        'title' => 'required',
            'search' => 'required',
            'amount' => 'required|integer',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        'body' => 'required',
      ];

      $this->validate($request, $rules); 

      $data = $request->all(); 
      $request->session()->put($data); 
      return view('mail.confirm', compact("data"));
    }


    public function complete()
    { 

      $data = $request->all(); # 3)
      $request->session()->put($data); # 4)
      Contact::create($request->all());
　　　
      $data = session()->all();

      Mail::send([　・・・
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the parameter type $request as you did in confirm function.In your complete function, you don't declare $request variable and accessing it without declaration

```
public function confirm(Request $request)
{
  $rules = [   
    'title' => 'required',
    'search' => 'required',
    'amount' => 'required|integer',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'body' => 'required',
  ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules); 
    $data = $request->all(); 

    // setting session key value for you data
    $request->session()->put('data',$data);

    return view('mail.confirm', compact("data"));
}

/*
 *　complete page 
 */
public function complete(Request $request)
 { 
   // after confirm button click get data from session with key '@data' ;
   $data = $request->session()->pull('data');

   // get token value in variable and remove from data set so we can use mass assignement 
   $token = array_shift($data);

//    creating record
   $Contact = Contact::create($data);

   Mail::send(['text' => 'mail.temp'], $data, function($message) use($data){
    $message->to($data["email"])->bcc('lara_admin@sakura.ne.jp')->from('1110.ne.jp')->subject('thnak you。');});


   Mail::send(['text' => 'mail.admintemp'], $data, function($message) use($data){
    $message->to('lara_admin@sakura.ne.jp')->from('emailconf@.ne.jp')->subject('you got order');});



    $data = session()->regenerateToken();
    return view('mail.complete');
}
```

Comment: Dear @shareyar Thank you for answering me. I apreciate. I'm still not sure Do me a favor Could you show me correct code please?

Comment: try something like this

    protected function confrim(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

   
    protected function complete(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

Comment: Dear @shareyar Thank you very much your help! Sorry I've took long time. since I got your help I had been tring but I couldn't add it to my codd. my app alwasy show error... Do me a favor Could you look my Controller and add your perfect function please?  Here is my whole controller code  https://jsfiddle.net/goldlight/4dfmh9v5/1/

Comment: Why you are trying to do this in different function when you can do it one function?Can you explain your scenario?

Comment: Dear @shareyar. You mean why I made confirm page? I'm Japanese. and In Japanese. we make confirm page in contact form. its kind of custom so... I would like to make like this.

Comment: check complete function i do a little change in it

Comment: Dear @shareyar Thank you for understanding me. I tried your code but it still didn't work. maybe I wrote it wrong positon. Could you show me whole controller code please?

Comment: Dear @shareyar Thank you for being so nice. I update whole controller code here https://jsfiddle.net/goldlight/4dfmh9v5/3/

Comment: NO problem can you tell why you are returning view and what is the purpose of it.
Instead of returning to view you can create Contact and then after sending email render you view and show the message.

Comment: Dear @shareyar  The reason. One is what I told you that I say its Japan Email form custom. 1st page is input page. 2nd page is " Are you sure these info? If you okay click "submit" bottom" .Last 3rd page is " Thank you for contact me " In Stackoverflow many people asked me why you don't validate or Ask "Is it okay?" at 1st page? Yes that's true but for me its too dificult . If I'm good at coding I can make it like that. but for now I use old way and its easy for me.

Comment: Ok now i know the whole senario , just do little help can you show your confirm button code means is it a form or just an anchor tag .

Comment: Check updated code and it will work for you as far as I know the whole scenario and update your code with this.

Comment: Dear @shareyar This is perfect!!! You are truly marvelous person! Thank you very much! I really apreciate took many time for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @kagemaru and good see that your issue has been resolved :)